# Advice on django form change emailing

Tags: django, email, signals

Goal: On submission of a form to add/update/delete objects an email is sent out with the current contents of the DB object and the new contents of the DB object in html.

Example

> Object Title was **oldTitle** and has been changed to **newTitle** 
>   Object Date was **oldDate** and has been changed to **newDate**

My assumption this can be done two different ways. Directly through send_mail or via signals. My gut leans towards using signals to make sure I can grab previous content and the new content but I am not quite sure if this is the right way to go. Any advice you can give would be much appreciated. I couldn't find very much on this subject online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue up the message to be sent in the `pre_save` signal, and send (or reap) them in the `post_save` signal.

Comment: This is along the lines I was thinking. I will give this a shot and see if it will work the way I need it to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `save()` in your model objects, and grabbing the fields in question before calling `super()`.

Here's a database email queue I wrote, which may help you with the actual sending of the mail:

http://gist.github.com/629663

Comment: Interesting, I will check this out. Thanks!